# clearInterval() is not working. Strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, console, clearinterval

This is the code:

```
var LOAD = window.setInterval("LOADING()", 50);

function LOADING()   {
  var y = document.getElementById("cse");
  var str = y.innerHTML;
  if (str !== "Loading") {
    setTimeout('INPUTAI()', 100);
    window.clearInterval(LOAD);
    console.log('Google paieška užsikrovė');
  }  
}
```

Then page loads and then "Loading" dissmises, in my Google Chrome console I see "Google paieška užsikrovė", but it keeps writing to console, and writing... So clearInterval not works.

**Problem solved**: changed to

> var LOAD = window.setInterval(LOADING, 50);

Thanks ;)

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net illustrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: You can not define stuff like this window.setInterval("LOADING()", 50);. Modify this with window.setInterval(LOADING, 50). Same stuff at setTimeout.

Comment: @stefanz, why not? It's incorrect I agree, it would be better to use `window.setInterval(LOADING, ...` but this doesn't mean that ` window.setInterval("LOADING()"` wouldn't work.

Comment: `window.setInterval("LOADING()", 50);` is perfectly valid javascript. I repeat it shouldn't be used but that's not the problem here.

Comment: log the `str` value. is it "Loading" ?

Comment: THanks for fast respond. I can say, that changing to window.setInterval(LOADING, 50) helped :O

Comment: Try log the value of `LOAD` near the clearTimout line, I suspect it would be `undefined`.

Comment: Don't update your question with the answer, choose one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` does not need the function's `()`:

```
 var LOAD = window.setInterval(LOADING, 50);
  setTimeout(INPUTAI, 100);
```

Also, as many people ponted out, the problem *may* be with the `#cse` element's content not being exactly `"Loading"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out?

```
var LOAD = setInterval(LOADING, 50);

function LOADING()   {
  var y = document.getElementById("cse");
  var str = y.innerHTML;
  if (str !== "Loading") {
    setTimeout(INPUTAI, 100);
    clearInterval(LOAD);
    console.log('Google paieška užsikrove');
  }  
}
```